# Why is a Tkinter Button returning None when using in function?

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter

I am making a GUI Hangman and I have made 26 buttons for each letter. I want to disable the button when pressed but I can't seem to call the variable from the function.

Here is an example button:

```
self.letter_n = tk.Button(self, text="n", command=lambda: self.take_guess("n"), width=2, height=2).place(x=450, y=400, anchor="center") # Letter "n" (Button)
```

I have tried to do this but `button` returns `None` for some reason.

```
def take_guess(self, letter):
    button = getattr(self, f"letter_{letter}")
    button.configure(state="disabled")
```

I have also tried to make a dictionary for each letter and variable like this:

```
self.dict_of_letters = {"a": self.letter_a,
                    "b": self.letter_b} # And so on...
```

And using it in the function like this but it still returns `None`

```
def take_guess(self, letter):
    button = self.dict_of_letters[letter]
```

Can anybody help me? This is really annoying and i'm not sure how to do this...
I'm happy to provide more info.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In function chaining, the return value of the *rightmost* function in the chain is assigned to the variable. For example, in

```
var = foo().bar().baz()
```

`var` is assigned whatever is returned from `baz()`. In your example, you not only create a button instance with `tk.Button()`, you then call its `place()` function. `tk.Button()` returns a button object, but `place()` simply returns `None`.

The solution is to create all the button instances, store them in a list or dict, then iterate over all of them to `place()` them.

Comment: But I need to place them in a specific order to make them look nice. What if I place them seperately? So I do: `button = tk.Button(...)` and `button.place(...)` seperately?

Comment: Works now :) Thank you so much!

Comment: @KevinApetrei yes, as I assume you just saw, that also will work.